# Tidyjson: is there an 'exit_object()' equivalent?

Tags: json, r

I'm using package `tidyjson` to parse a json string and extract the key values into columns. The json in nested, and while I can drill down at a node, I can't figure out a way to go up to the previous level. The code is below:

```
library(tidyjson)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)


input <- '{
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": 30,
      "social": {
            "married": "yes",
            "kids": "no"
      },
      "work": {
            "title": "engineer",
            "salary": 5000
      } 
}'


output <- input %>% as.tbl_json() %>%
      spread_values(name = jstring("name"),
                    age = jnumber("age")) %>%
      enter_object("social") %>% 
      spread_values(married = jstring("married"),
                    kids = jstring("kids")) %>%
      #### I would need an exit_obeject() here
      enter_object("work") %>%
      spread_values(title = jstring("title"),
                    salary = jnumber("salary"))
```

Comment: Maybe file a request here: https://github.com/sailthru/tidyjson/issues ? I'd be interested, too, in what the right strategy would be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an overlooked piece of functionality within tidyjson is the ability to use more complex paths in the `jnumber`, `jstring`, etc. functions.

You can do something like the following without "entering an object."  I find this to be a very satisfying solution, for the most part.  Perhaps more satisfying than multiple enter/exits.

```
input <- '{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 30,
  "social": {
        "married": "yes",
        "kids": "no"
  },
  "work": {
        "title": "engineer",
        "salary": 5000
  } 
}'


output <- input %>% as.tbl_json() %>%
   spread_values(
    name = jstring('name')
    , age=jnumber('age')
    , married=jstring('social','married')
    , kids = jstring('social','kids')
    , title= jstring('work','title')
    , salary = jnumber('work','salary')
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a note in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyjson/vignettes/introduction-to-tidyjson.html):

> "Note that there are often situations where there are multiple arrays
>   or objects of differing types that exist at the same level of the JSON
>   hierarchy. In this case, you need to use enter_object() to enter each
>   of them in separate pipelines to create separate data.frames that can
>   then be joined relationally."

As such I've been staging my tidyjson commands and putting the outputs together with merge, e.g.:

```
# first the high-level values
output_table <- input_tbl_json %>%
    spread_values(val1 = jstring('val1'),
                  val2 = jnumber('val2'))

# then enter an object and get something from inside, merging it as a new column
output_table <- merge(output_table, 
                      input_tbl_json %>%
                        enter_object('thing') %>%
                          spread_values(val3 = jstring('thing1')),
                      by = c('document.id'))
```

output table columns should look like `| document.id | val1 | val2 | val3 |`

That workflow may fall over with operations like gather_keys() that add rows, but I haven't had call to test it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I ran into a similar problem but with `json_length` instead of `jstring` and friends where the accepted answer cannot be applied!